# GROUP BY on multiple columns MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I have two table with 1-M relation.
1) com_event (1).
2) com_event_schedules (m)

I want to fetch all the schedules of all future events. Following are the condition which not working with my query.

1. if schedules.location_id and schedule.date_of_service are same, such a records should be GROUP BY. I wrote a following query for the following. But it is not working in some scenarios. And those scenarios are.

i) if date_of_service is same but location are different it is still grouping records.
ii) if location_id are are same and date_of_service are different it is grouping future dates schedules with current date schedule.

Following is my query:

```
SELECT schedules.*
FROM com_event event
LEFT JOIN com_event_schedules schedules ON event.id=schedules.event_id
WHERE schedules.date_of_service > CURDATE()
AND deleted=0
GROUP BY schedules.location_id,
schedules.date_of_service
```

Any solutions on that in mysql query.
My requirement is records should be GROUP only if schedules.date_of_service and schedules.location_id are same.

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results.

Comment: Do you really mean GROUP BY (because you're not using any grouped aggregation functions such as SUM(), MAX(), AVG(), etc) or do you mean DISTINCT?

Answer (score 0):

GROUP BY is used to group the result of a query and calculate the count, sum, etc of this grouping.

I am not sure, but I think you want a distinct result set.

```
SELECT DISTINCT schedules.*
FROM com_event event
JOIN com_event_schedules schedules ON event.id=schedules.event_id
WHERE schedules.date_of_service > CURDATE()
AND deleted=0
```

And a left join is not in order, because you actually filter on content of schedules.